# How to dynamically generate JSon in Gatling?

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I have the following two methods:

```
def randomStartMethod() : Long = {
  var range = 1000L
  var r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(10L*range)
  var randomStart = 1396024675000L + r
  return randomStart
}

def randomStopMethod() : Long = {
  var range = 1000L
  val r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(10L*range)
  val randomStop =  1396024675000L + r*2L
  return randomStop
}
```

Then I add it to the request body like this:

```
val activity = repeat(10, "i") {
      exec(http("POST activity post")
        .post("/activity/")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1")
        .header("accept", "*/*")
        .body(StringBody(
          s"""
             |{
             |    "id": "activityId",
             |    "type": "run",
             |    "start_epoch_ms": "${randomStartMethod()}",
             |    "end_epoch_ms": "${randomStop()}",
             |    "metrics": [
             |        {
             |            "type": "distance",
             |            "unit": "KM",
             |            "source": "nike.running.ios",
             |            "values": [
             |                {
             |                    "start_epoch_ms": "${randomStartMethod()}",
             |                    "end_epoch_ms": "${randomStopMethod()}",
             |                    "value": 2.0
             |                }
             |
            |            ]
             |        }
             |    ]
             |}
          """.stripMargin)).
        asJSON
        .check(status.is(202))
        .check(
          jsonPath(
            "$.activityId").saveAs("message")
        )
        .check(bodyString.
          transform(_.split("\""
          )(3)).saveAs(
          "changeToken"))

      ).exec(
        session => {
          val maybeId =
            session.get(
              "message").asOption[String]
          println(maybeId)
          session
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

But here the values are not generated dynamically when I use with feed. Can someone suggest how to generate the random numbers every time throughout the run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it, by adding methods in gatling:

```
package simulations.syncservice

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.math._

class PostActivitySimulation extends Simulation {

  var startEpoch = 0L;
  var stopEpoch = 0L;

  val appId = Map("appId" -> "NIKEREEBOK")

  //Sync service parameters
  val syncUrl = "https://YOURURL.COM"

  var httpConf = http.baseURL(syncUrl)

  def startGenerator() :Long = {
    var startNum = 1396024675000L + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(90000L)
    startEpoch = startNum;
    return startNum
  }
  def stopGenerator() :Long = {
    var stopNum = 1396335695000L + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(90000L)
    stopEpoch = stopNum;
    return stopNum
  }


  val postActivity = scenario("POST Activity")
    .exec(http("POST activity post")
      .post("/activity/")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1")
      .header("accept" , "*/*")
      .body(StringBody(session =>
        s"""
           |{
           |    "id": "activityId",
           |    "type": "run",
           |    "start_epoch_ms": "${startGenerator()}",
           |    "end_epoch_ms": "${stopGenerator()}",
           |    "metrics": [
           |        {
           |            "type": "distance",
           |            "unit": "KM",
           |            "source": "nike.running.ios",
           |            "values": [
           |                {
           |                    "start_epoch_ms": "${startEpoch}",
           |                    "end_epoch_ms": "${stopEpoch}",
           |                    "value": 2.0
           |                }
           |
            |            ]
           |        }
           |    ]
           |}
          """.stripMargin)).asJSON
      .check(status.is(202))
      .check(
        jsonPath("$.activityId").saveAs("activityId")
      )
      .check(bodyString.transform(_.split("\"")(3)).saveAs("changeToken"))
    )
    .exec(
      session => {
        val activityId = session.get("activityId").asOption[String]
        println(activityId)
        session
      }
    )

  setUp(
    postActivity.inject
    (nothingFor(2 seconds),
      atOnceUsers(30),
      rampUsers(200) over(1000 seconds))
      .protocols(httpConf))
}
```